# Remove mydomain.com says: from popup window, and auto close it

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a comparison module on a site I'm making and when a product is added to the list it opens a popup window that says "Localhost says:", followed by a message that is set in the code.

The script code is very small:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function compareNew(obj, action) {
    var jqno=jQuery.noConflict();
    jqno.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      cache: false,
      data:{
        'compare_id': obj, 
        'com_action': action,
        'msg':'yes', 
        'securityToken':'<?php echo $_SESSION['securityToken'];?>'
      },
      url: "ajax_compare.php",
      success: function(msg){
        alert(msg);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

I'm trying to remove the Localhost says: text, but can't see anything related to it in the ajax_compare file, or the jscript file that calls the php file.

I would also like to remove the close button and have it fade and close within 3 seconds or so, but again I can't find any reference to this button.

Are these something that is a 'built in' part of a pop-up of this type?

Comment: `Alert`s are not customizable.  You'll need to switch to a DOM-based popup if you want to change its appearance.

Comment: @DanielBeck Is there any other option I can use that would be customizable?

Comment: There are dozens of libraries for this sort of thing, yes.  (I can't really recommend one over another; for one it's discouraged on SO as basically a matter of opinion, for another it really depends on what the rest of your codebase looks like).  Essentially they all draw DOM nodes into the document instead of using browser features like alert().

Comment: @DanielBeck Can you give me a 'hint' on what google might call such a library so I can take a look at the variety on offer?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that, I guess I don't need to be *that* coy.  "notification", "popup boxes", "dom popup", sometimes people incorrectly call them "popup windows" even though strictly speaking that means something else; "toast notifications" (which I've only just now understood the pun, groan), lightbox, modal...  all of those will give you various variations on the idea

Comment: @DanielBeck Thanks, I'll take a look.
I'm guessing I need to replace the line "alert(msg);" with something more customizable.

Answer (score 0):

The close button is built into the alert function.

As for the "Localhost says:", it's fixed to be the domain of the website.

Comment: So there is no way to override it and have an autoclose?

Comment: you could use a custom alert that autohides.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
 alert(msg);
```

This should solve it.